# Is there a "readable content guide" on Android?

Tags: android, user-interface

Now that it's 2022 and Android tablets (and their cousins, foldables) are getting more prevalent, I got my interest ramped up in building a better tablet version of one of my apps. Coming from iOS, there is a useful layout feature that one can use when designing tablet UIs called "readable content guide". [Apple describes it](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622644-readablecontentguide) as follows:

> This layout guide defines an area that can easily be read without forcing users to move their head to track the lines. The readable content area follows the following rules:
>
> The readable content guide never extends beyond the view’s layout margin guide.
>
> The readable content guide is vertically centered inside the layout margin guide.
>
> The readable content guide’s width is equal to or less than the readable width defined for the current dynamic text size.

A picture is worth a thousand words. To the right is some text aligned to the readable content guide (the left version just spans the width of the main view):
[image: readable content guide example]

Looks great when reading long-form content, doesn't it? Thus, my question:

**is there a standardized version (that is, without me having to code one myself) of a feature similar to this on Android?**

Now that version 12L is out, I thought it would incorporate something like this, especially with Google promoting Jetpack Compose (and other new UI extensions) as a faster and easier way to build UIs.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what a comfortable width is you can use android:maxWidth="yourWidth" to limit the width of your textview to what you want